# Updating or adding sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I am struggling with very weird problem in MongoDB, what I want is that the query updates document if the condition matches and if not creates new (upsert).

The problem:
I get the correct results from the callback, as this returns the newly inserted document. But what appears ***the query gets never inserted in database***.

What I think causes this, is the $set part, is looking for array but instead this must be object:

```
boards [
  // Looks for element 48 and inserts there
] 

{ '$set': 
   { 'boards.48.acl': 'ReadWrite',
     'boards.48.status': 'goal' } }
```

Here is the query:

```
// the 11 is example input
var scoreKey  = util.format('scores.' + 11),
    aclKey    = scoreKey + '.acl',
    statusKey = scoreKey + '.status',
    setQuery  = {
        $set: { }
    };

setQuery['$set'][aclKey] = acl;
setQuery['$set'][statusKey] = status;

db.sessions.findAndModify({
    query: { '_id': sid },
    update: setQuery,
    upsert: true,
    new: true
}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    else {
        console.log(res);
        return cb(null, res);
    }
});
```

// Update

Well it seems all kind of the changes to database are silently failing, so the query seems to be correct.

Comment: To make database changes fail loudly, change your [write concerns](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) or call [GetLastError()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/) after them.

Comment: Can you please show us an example document?

Comment: If you could give us the results of "GetLastError", that would be very helpful.

Comment: Also, heads up, doing upserts with array indexes can lead to potentially surprising behavior. While doing $set update to an existing array will extend the array to meet your required index, an upsert will not create a proper array but rather a subdocument with a key of the index you gave.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I found out whats caused problem. As I am updating the session collection and also using connect-mongo middleware which destructs all the set data. So my update was always success but the middlewere removed it.